# understanding this race condition in numba parallelization

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

There is an example in Numba doc about parallel race condition

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def prange_wrong_result(x):
    n = x.shape[0]
    y = np.zeros(4)
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        y[:]+= x[i]
    return y
```

I have ran it, and it indeed outputs abnormal result like

```
prange_wrong_result(np.ones(10000))
#array([5264., 5273., 5231., 5234.])
```

then I tried to change the loop into

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def prange_wrong_result(x):
    n = x.shape[0]
    y = np.zeros(4)
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        y+= x[i]
    return y
```

and it outputs

```
prange_wrong_result(np.ones(10000))
#array([10000., 10000., 10000., 10000.])
```

I have read some race condition explanation. But I still don't understand

1. why second example has no racing condition? What is the difference between `y[:]=` vs `y=`
2. why output of four elements in first example is not the same?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your first example you have multiple threads/processes that share the same array and read + assign to the shared array. The `y[:] += x[i]` is roughly equivalent to:

```
y[0] += x[i]
y[1] += x[i]
y[2] += x[i]
y[3] += x[i]
```

In fact the `+=` is just syntactic sugar for a read, addition, and assignment operation, so `y[0] += x[i]` is in fact:

```
_value = y[0]
_value = _value + x[i]
y[0] = _value
```

The loop body is executed simultaneously by multiple threads/processes and that's where the race-condition comes in. The example on Wikipedia on a race-condition applies here:

> [image]

That's why the returned array contains wrong values and why each element might be different. Because it's simply non-deterministic which thread/process runs when. So in some cases there's a race-condition on one element, sometimes on none, sometimes on multiple elements.

However the numba developers have implemented some supported reductions where no race-condition occurs. One of them is `y +=`. The important thing here is that it's the variable itself, instead of a slice/element of the variable. In that case numba does something very clever. They copy the initial value of the variable for each thread/process and then operate on that copy. After the parallel loop finished they add up the copied values. Taking your second example and assuming if it used 2 processes it would look roughly like this:

```
y = np.zeros(4)
y_1 = y.copy()
y_2 = y.copy()
for i in nb.prange(n):
    if is_process_1:
        y_1[:] += x[i]
    if is_process_2:
        y_2[:] += x[i]
y += y_1
y += y_2
```

Since each thread has its own array there's no potential for a race-condition. For numba to be able to deduce this you have to follow their restrictions. The documentation states that numba creates race-condition-free parallel code for `+=` on scalars and arrays (`y += x[i]`), but **not on array elements/slices** (`y[:] += x[i]` or `y[1] += x[i]`).

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation. BTW, you mentioned that `y[0] += x[i]` is actually three steps. Why it is not a single step `y[0] = y[0]+x[i]`? Is there some internal inspecting tool that can prove it is really three steps?

Comment: That was just counting the operations (behind the scenes it could be even more): `y[0] += ...` is equivalent to `y[0] = y[0] + ...`, the `y[0]` is one access-operation, the `+ ...` is one arithmetic-operation and `y[0] =` is one assignment-operation. With numba you can inspect the generated code, llvm, and asm using `prange_wrong_result.inspect_types()`, `.inspect_llvm()`, and `.inspect_asm()` respectively (after running the function). However that's probably hard to digest and understand. However counting the "visible operations" generally gives a good indication for the lower bound.