# Avoid Race Condition in Numba

Tags: python, race-condition, numba

Here is a toy `njit` function that takes in a distance matrix, loops through each row of the matrix, and records the minimum value in each column and also which row that minimum value came from. However, IIUC, with the use of prange, this could possibly cause a race condition (especially for larger input arrays):

```
from numba import njit, prange
import numpy as np

@njit
def some_transformation_func(D, row_i):
   """
   This function applies some transformation to the ith row (`row_i`) in the `D` matrix in place. 
   However, the transformation time is random (but all less than a second), which means 
   that the rows can take
   """

    # Apply some inplace transformation on the ith row of D


@njit(parallel=True)
def some_func(D):
    P = np.empty((D.shape[1]))
    I = np.empty((D.shape[1]), np.int64)
    P[:] = np.inf
    I[:] = -1

    for row in prange(D.shape[0]):
        some_transformation_func(D, row)
        for col in range(D.shape[1]):
            if P[col] > D[row, col]:
                P[col] = D[row, col]
                I[col] = row

    return P, I

if __name__ == "__main__":
    D = np.array([[4,1,6,9,9], 
                  [1,3,8,2,7], 
                  [2,8,0,0,1],
                  [3,7,4,6,5]
                 ])
    P, I = some_func(D)
    print(P)
    print(I)

    # [1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
    # [1 0 2 2 2]
```

How would I confirm whether or not there is a race condition (especially if D is very large with many more rows and columns)? And, more importantly, if there is a race condition, how could I avoid it?

Comment: Not writing an answer as I am no Numba expert, reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596794/understanding-this-race-condition-in-numba-parallelization makes me believe your lines `P[col] > D[row, col]: P[col] = D[row, col]` are a race, because they are two separate lines, with no lock, reading and writing the same memory.

Comment: As for testing, like you said, as the array gets larger, the probability for NOT hitting a race condition inconsistency goes lower. I would suggest a naiive consecutive implementation, and a comparison usig `numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal` on very large arrays. If equal, then the probability of a race is very low.

Comment: And another thing, In python, unlike Matlab, it is considered unconventional to use capital letters in local variable names.

Comment: If any of this helped please let me know

Comment: I appreciate your responses. But what I really need help with us how to avoid the race condition (without losing parallel performance)

Comment: I did come across the link that you had provided and I had read that certain reduction types were allowed but none seemed to be what I am looking for https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.11/prange.html

Comment: Try posting the actual required calculation, as sequential code. Maynlbe it will be easier to help

Comment: I think I found a solution. I'll post it once I've tested it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these situations, instead of setting `prange` to the size of the array, the best thing to do is to manually chunk up the data into `n_threads` number of chunks, then to distribute the processing accordingly, and finally perform a reduction. So, something like this:

```
from numba import njit, prange, config
import numpy as np

@njit
def wrapper_func(thread_idx, start_indices, stop_indices, D, P, I):
    for row in range(start_indices[thread_idx], stop_indices[thread_idx]):
        some_transformation_func(D, row)
        for col in range(D.shape[1]):
            if P[thread_idx, col] > D[row, col]:
                P[thread_idx, col] = D[row, col]
                I[thread_idx, col] = row


@njit
def some_transformation_func(D, row_i):
   """
   This function applies some transformation to the ith row (`row_i`) in the `D` matrix in place. 
   However, the transformation time is random (but all less than a second), which means 
   that the rows can take
   """

    # Apply some inplace transformation on the ith row of D


@njit(parallel=True)
def some_func(D):
    n_threads = config.NUMBA_NUM_THREADS  # Let's assume that there are 2 threads
    P = np.empty((n_threads, D.shape[1]))
    I = np.empty((n_threads, D.shape[1]), np.int64)
    P[:, :] = np.inf
    I[:, :] = -1

    start_indices = np.array([0, 2], np.int64)
    stop_indices = np.array([2, 4], np.int64)  # Note that these are exclusive

    for thread_idx in prange(n_threads):
        wrapper_func(thread_idx, start_indices, stop_indices, D, P, I)

    # Perform reduction from all threads and store results in P[0]
    for thread_idx in range(1, n_threads):
        for i in prange(l):
            if P[0, i] > P[thread_idx, i]:
                P[0, i] = P[thread_idx, i]
                I[0, i] = I[thread_idx, i]

    return P[0], I[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    D = np.array([[4,1,6,9,9], 
                  [1,3,8,2,7], 
                  [2,8,0,0,1],
                  [3,7,4,6,5]
                 ])
    P, I = some_func(D)
    print(P)
    print(I)

    # [1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
    # [1 0 2 2 2]
```

Note that this will cost you more memory (exactly `n_threads` more memory) but you benefit from the parallelization. Additionally, the code becomes cleaner and much easier to maintain. What one needs to do is figure the best way to chunk up the data and determine the `start_row` and `stop_row` (exclusive) indices.